# ROS2 - tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster and rclcpp_lifecycle::LifecycleNode

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to create a TransformBroadcaster inside my LifecycleNode, but the constructor of `tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster` requires a `rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr`.

This may be a silly question, but I cannot fill the missing part:

```
    std::shared_ptr<tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster> mTransformPoseBroadcaster;
    mTransformPoseBroadcaster = std::make_shared<tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster>(??????????);
```

Thank you for help

Walter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302459/ros2---tf2_ros::transformbroadcaster-and-rclcpp_lifecycle::lifecyclenode/) by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 541 on 2018-09-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `tf2_ros` interface, which pre-dates lifecycle nodes and the node interfaces in `rclcpp`, would need to be updated to take the "node interfaces" that it uses, which are the common element between `Node` and `LifecycleNode`. For example, maybe it should instead take a pointer to `rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeTopicsInterface` and a pointer to an instance of `rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeParametersInterface` instead of a pointer to a node.

A separate question is whether or not `tf2_ros` should create lifecycle topics or normal topics (should it work only in certain lifecycle states or always)?

I'd recommend opening an issue on the `ros2/geometry2` issue tracker (https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/issues) asking about this. I'm not sure if anyone will have time to implement this for you, but if you're interesting in contributing this feature for tf2 that would probably be a quicker way to get a solution for this.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on 2018-09-06**:
Yes, I think that it should be similar to executors that get a pointer to `NodeBaseInterface` when you add nodes.

Added issue: https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/issues/70

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on 2018-09-06**:
Actually I'm using a simple trick: I publish the TF2 as normal message and I made a "normal" node that subscribes and broadcasts using `tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster`

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on 2018-09-15**:
An update: using the node that subscribes to tf2 messages and broadcasts them it works, but there is a latency issue as i described here: https://answers.ros.org/question/303377/ros2-tf2-broadcasting-very-slow/